# In SQL Server 2005, how can I use database_b, do something, then use the old db database_a in TSQL?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In SQL Server 2005, how can I use database_b, do something, then use the old db database_a in TSQL? The following is my code but there is some problem with it. Who can help me to identity the problem? Great thanks.

```
DECLARE @old_database_name VARCHAR(200)
SET @old_database_name = db_name()

use mydatabase

create table t1(id int identity(1,1))

use @old_database_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use dynamic sql to do this.

e.g.

```
-- Do stuff in current DB here

EXECUTE ('USE mydatabase; create table t1(id int identity(1,1));')

-- Do more stuff in current DB here. This context will not have changed since before the EXECUTE statement
```

Comment: +1, that is how I'd do it. you could even do something like: `EXECUTE ('EXEC SomeOtherDatabase..SomeProcedure')` if you have a lot of stuff to do.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even using USE statements for this?

```
create table mydatabase.dbo.t1(id int identity(1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to AdaTheDev's "EXECUTE" example, but uses sp_executesql :

```
-- Do stuff in current DB here

EXECUTE mydatabase..sp_executesql N'create table t1(id int identity(1,1));'

-- Do more stuff in current DB here. This context will not have changed since before the EXECUTE statement
```